# Time-series plot for two lines using same variable but under different condition

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I want to create a two-line time-series plot for sales of tier1 brand and tier2 brand. I am using plot.ts(data$TotalSales) and I am wondering how can I add the condition Tier1="1" and Tier2="1" in it

Answer (score 0):

```
ts1 <- ts(c(2,4,3,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,2,7,2,5), start = 1, frequency = 4)
ts2 <- ts(c(2,5,6,2,2,6,2,2,5,2,5,2,2,1,5,1), start = 1, frequency = 4)
plot.ts(ts1, col = "red")
lines(ts2, col= "green")
```